# While using Simpledirectoryreader in Llamaindex I am getting an error with metadata

Tags: llama-index

def load_data():
documents=SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="./Splitted_csv/",recursive=True).load_data()
# documents=documents.
pc=Pinecone(api_key=APIKEY)
pinecone_index=pc.Index('law-poc')
# model_name = 'text-embedding-3-small'
# embed=OpenAIEmbedding(model=model_name)

```
# service_contexxt=ServiceContext.from_defaults(embed_model=embed)
vector_store=PineconeVectorStore(pinecone_index=pinecone_index,namespace='law-poc')
storagecontext=StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    documents,
    vector_store=vector_store,
    storage_context=storagecontext
    # service_context=service_contexxt,
    
    
)
return index
```

when I run this function, I am getting the below error:
raise PineconeApiException(http_resp=r)
pinecone.core.client.exceptions.PineconeApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 28 Feb 2024 14:20:44 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '146', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-pinecone-request-latency-ms': '298', 'x-pinecone-request-id': '1779100839530208671', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '59', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: {"code":3,"message":"Metadata value must be a string, number, boolean or list of strings, got 'null' for field 'last_accessed_date'","details":[]}

I think simpledirectoryreader is giving the metadata field 'last_accessed_date' as null.

I commented the last_accessed_Date in source code of simple directory reader and its working fine for me

llamaindex version:LlamaIndex  v0.10.13

Expecting to exclude last_accessesed_date in from metadata

Answer (score 0):

got the answer for my question, I have removed 'last_accessed_date' variable from the documents.

```
for doc in documents:
    k=vars(doc)
    del k['metadata']['last_accessed_date']
.......existing code
```